# A word or phrase for a person who doesn't accept new things

Tags: word-request

I mean that I need a word to describe a person who always opposes the development of society and has outdated concepts and ideas. For example, an Asian person who doesn't like people having tattoos or accept girls who have sex before marriage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most general term for what you're asking would be [**conservative**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/conservative). You can't get any more basic than that. This word has a lot of different meanings, but the basic idea is that a conservative person is someone who is averse to change and innovation and typically holds traditional values. That's how most dictionaries define it.

Example:

> My parents don't like this modern idea that you can have sex before marriage. They're very **conservative**.

Another term that can be used in a similar way to *conservative* is [**old-fashioned**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/old-fashioned). The meaning is exactly the same. Old-fashioned people tend to lean towards more traditional or conservative ideas or customs.

Example:

> My grandparents are strongly opposed to this modern idea that you can have sex before marriage. They're very **old-fashioned**, you know.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see:

- Red-pilled.
- Sensible.
- Wise.
- Traditionalist.
- Self-respecting.
- Red-blooded.

Comment: When and why are each of these suitable?

Answer (score 0):

Another word commonly used is **reactionary**.